# How can I check for the existence of an object in expression bindings using knockout punches?

Tags: knockout.js

If my variable isn't set, the view breaks and outputs the actual expression in the view.[image: error image]

I want to check for the existence of the variables first. I've tried

```
{{#if stats && stats.activity && stats.activity.last30Days}}
    <td>{{ stats.activity.last30Days | number }}</td>
{{#else}}
    <td>0</td>
{{/endif}}
```

and I've tried

```
<td>{{ (stats && stats.activity && stats.activity.last60Days) | number || 0 }}</td>
```

Comment: What is the variable that isn't set? How is your model? Without this information it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this kind of problem is to include all that logic in a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), which could be named something like `activityDisplayValue`. It has several advantages over including the expressions in the bindings:

- the bindings become much simpler, and readable
- it's much easier to test the view model
- the expressions can be easily reused if you have to bind them to different DOM elements

The second point is especially important. For example, if you open your browser console to examine the value, or you convert the whole model to JSON and show it in your view, you can easily check the computed expression.

A very interesting post regarding this advice: [Simplifying and Cleaning Up Views in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html).

However, if you still want to do it, even without seeing your model I think that the problem is that you are not invoking the observables, with `()` to extract their values and be able to access their properties. For example, if `stats` is an observable, you have to invoke it with `stats()` to get its value. See the `if` example at ko punches docs: `{{#ifnot items().length}}` which in this case unwraps and observable array to get it's `.length` property.

Comment: Using computed observables is not feasible in this case. `stats` is not an observable and neither are it's properties.

Comment: If using computed observable isn't feasible, at least a function that makes the calculation should be. Or in any case, adding the property to the model right before binding it.Why not?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<td>{{ stats && stats.activity && stats.activity.last60Days || 0 | number }}</td>
```